# FEniCS: custom quadrature rule

Tags: quadrature, fenics

For the numerical integration of reaction terms in my PDE on a 2D triangular mesh, I would like to use the scheme
$$
\int_T \Phi(x) \approx \frac{|T|}{3} (\Phi(x_0) + \Phi(x_1) + \Phi(x_2))
$$
where the $x_i$ are the triangle nodes.

How to specify this when `assemble`ing the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't specify quadrature rule to assembler but to form compiler. You can tweak `ffc/quadrature_schemes.py` for your needs or you can adjust generated code. In both cases you just supply your quadrature points and weights.

Comment: Luckily, `assemble()` has an `form_compiler_parameters` argument.

Comment: @Nico: Yes, but FFC seems to accept only `default` and `canonical` which is a scheme supplied by FIAT.

Comment: Indeed, `quadrature_schemes.py` doesn't seem to permit custom schemes.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the quadrature degree by setting

```
parameters["form_compiler_parameters"]["quadrature_degree"] = q
```

This will change the quadrature degree such that polynomials of degree q are integrated exactly.

FEniCS will try to autodetect the necessary quadrature degree so this should normally not be needed. However, in some cases you might want to underintegrate by setting a lower value of q.

Comment: I skimmed through `FFC/ffc/quadrature_schemes.py` to see what schemes are used for the particular degrees, but the "lumping" scheme that I'd like to use is not implemented.